# The Art of Misdirection

Tags: cipher

You're part of a special intelligence operation trying to predict the location of the next strike for a notorious terrorist group. This group has proven that they are willing to kill innocent people in suicide bombings in order to further their 'cause' - spreading terror amongst the people. We have infiltrated their IRC network, which we believe they are using to plan and execute their next attack. Here is a snapshot of their most recent IRC activity:

```
[12:24:47] <+ackb1> so you know
[12:25:10] <+xeggs> ??
[12:25:15] <+ackb1> you know what were doing next
[12:25:23] <+ackb1> that thing
[12:25:24] <+ackb1> you know what i mean
[12:25:46] <+xeggs> oh yeah...
[12:25:51] <+xeggs> :)
[12:25:55] <+ackb1> where are we doing it
[12:26:00] <+xeggs> AGLAZP YSW3ABCGMF 2QJ QBMKR LU5AM 2kTPMWI R2IWUN U6L KZRYEFQCA
[12:26:03] <+xeggs> AB 155d 86aiiai jjjj
[12:26:12] <+xeggs> zz4!!! 
[12:26:16] <+ackb1> how do i read that
[12:26:21] <+xeggs> you know...
[12:26:25] <+xeggs> name of my favourite restaurant
[12:26:45] <+xeggs> as key ;)
[12:27:00] <+ackb1> haha i see
[12:27:02] <+ackb1> well 
[12:27:17] <+ackb1> very nice :)
[12:27:30] <+ackb1> will you be there?
[12:27:32] <+xeggs> no i need to organise
[12:27:52] <+xeggs> im sure ull be right
[12:28:00] <+ackb1> this time we can make a difference
[12:28:05] <+xeggs> show em what we're made of? xd
[12:28:21] <+ackb1> wait
[12:28:26] <+ackb1> what time??
[12:28:40] <+xeggs> %%^pp00>?`~
[12:29:00] <+ackb1> oh
[12:29:01] <+ackb1> ok
[12:29:08] <+ackb1> will u be there?
[12:29:23] <+xeggs> nope
[12:29:37] <+xeggs> i gotta organise the next one
[12:29:56] <+ackb1> ah i see
[12:30:11] <+ackb1> shame, i dont see u very often
[12:30:24] <+ackb1> i might not even see you ever again... :(
[12:30:29] <+xeggs> ah dont worry
[12:30:34] <+xeggs> for a good cause
[12:30:54] <+xeggs> youre making a big difference
[12:31:14] <+xeggs> this movement could never survive
[12:31:22] <+xeggs> w/o people like you
[12:31:27] <+xeggs> =)
[12:31:45] <+ackb1> eehhhh i guess
[12:31:50] <+ackb1> well, thanks for telling me all the details
[12:31:51] <+ackb1> i gtg soon
[12:32:11] <+xeggs> WAIT
[12:32:17] <+xeggs> before u go
[12:32:26] <+xeggs> i need to tell you one more thing
[12:32:48] <+ackb1> ??????
[12:32:53] <+ackb1> what
[12:33:09] <+xeggs> A78djwBw!0enw?;;dw'_=
[12:33:22] <+xeggs> +dw[]aJWJw!w7#@dw^k
[12:33:42] <+xeggs> Na<>?"]\Wj1aW"
[12:33:57] <+xeggs> JJJJJ
[12:34:10] <+xeggs> =) =)
[12:34:25] <+ackb1> ahhahah
[12:34:43] <+ackb1> you made my day
[12:35:01] <+ackb1> ok cya
[12:35:16] <+xeggs> bye
[12:35:39] +ackb1 [~ackb1@hidden.obsfucateirc.net] has quit [leaving]
```

Unfortunately, from the IRC logs it looks like they are communicating in some sort of weird code. We have set our best cryptographers on it, but they came up with nothing.

We can't afford to make loose guesses as to their next target - lives are at stake!

***Can you help determine the location and time of the terrorists' next strike?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The location and time of the terrorists' next strike is:

> the **Pentagon** at **5:00 pm tomorrow**

The important clues appear to be:

> - "The Art of Misdirection" suggests that the initial observation of the weird code could be misleading
>  - the weird code seems to be several different codes but none are recognizable
>  - the words "as key (ASCII)", "time", "difference", and "right"

The actual code is in:

> the **number of seconds between subsequent times** which are:
>
> ```
> 23 5 8 1 22 5 4 5 3 9 4 5 4 20 15 2 15 13 2 20 8 5 16 5 14 20 1 7 15 14 19 15 13 5 5 20 20 8 5 18 5 1 20 6 9 22 5 16 13 20 15 13 15 18 18 15 23
> ```
>
> - Now the numbers can be converted to a letter of the alphabet which provides:
>  WEHAVEDECIDEDTOBOMBTHEPENTAGONSOMEETTHEREATFIVEPMTOMORROW **-or-**
>  **We have decided to bomb the Pentagon so meet there at five pm tomorrow**

Nice puzzle, Tryth. Thanks.